# Join two query in the same table on different month and sum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get table that have sum of `member_total_point` column at `MONTH(NOW())` and column at `MONTH(NOW() INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`. How can I select the table?

### edit

I've should not used [..] on select

and this my new query:

```
SELECT la.member_created, la.member_api_domain, la.member_api_campaign, 
      la.total, lb.total_now
FROM (SELECT member_created, member_api_domain, member_api_campaign, SUM(member_total_point) AS 'total' 
     FROM lalights_member WHERE YEAR(member_created)=YEAR(NOW()) 
     AND MONTH(member_created)= MONTH(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
     GROUP BY member_api_campaign ) AS la 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT member_created,SUM(member_total_point) 
     AS 'total_now' 
     FROM lalights_member WHERE YEAR(member_created)=YEAR(NOW()) 
     AND MONTH(member_created)= MONTH(NOW()) 
     ORDER BY member_api_campaign DESC) AS lb 
ON la.member_created = lb.member_created
```

but error apear this on SQLyog:

> '[total], lb.[total_now] FROM (Select member_created, member_api_domain, member_a' at line 1

im using MySQL 5.1..

### sample data:

```
member_created       member_api_domain  member_api_campaign member_total_point
--------------       -----------------  ------------------- ------------------
2015-09-22 18:30:20  domain             campaign             4 (september)
2015-09-22 18:30:20  domain             campaign             7 (september)
2015-08-22 18:30:20  domain             campaign             2 (august)
2015-08-22 18:30:20  domain             campaign             7 (august)
2015-09-22 18:30:20  asdf               jujuju               4 (september)
2015-08-22 18:30:20  asdf               jujuju               9 (august)
```

### sample output:

```
member_api_campaign this_month last_1month last_2month
------------------- ---------- ----------- -----------
domain              campaign   11(september) 9 (august)
asdf                jujuju     4 (september) 9 (august)
```

just remind, now is `October`.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
We need sample data and desire output to find an answer faster, otherwise we will be wasting time guessing what you need. You also could create your schema with data using **http://www.sqlfiddle.com**

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks for reminder, i'll do it next time :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza edited sir, hope you help :) thank you..

Comment: [SOLVED] just change "ON la.member_api_domain = lb.member_api_domain AND la.member_api_campaign = lb.member_api_campaign"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change single quote (mean string) for side quote or just remove the quotes for field alias

  ```
  'total'     for `total`
  'total_now' for `total_now`
  ```
- Remove       `ORDER BY member_api_campaign DESC`

.

```
SELECT la.member_created
    ,la.member_api_domain
    ,la.member_api_campaign
    ,la.total
    ,lb.total_now
FROM (
    SELECT member_created
          ,member_api_domain
          ,member_api_campaign
          ,SUM(member_total_point) AS 'total'
    FROM lalights_member
    WHERE YEAR(member_created) = YEAR(NOW())
      AND MONTH(member_created) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    GROUP BY member_api_campaign
    ) AS la
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT member_created
          ,SUM(member_total_point) AS 'total_now'
    FROM lalights_member
    WHERE YEAR(member_created) = YEAR(NOW())
      AND MONTH(member_created) = MONTH(NOW())
    ) AS lb ON la.member_created = lb.member_created
```

Comment: thanks for answer :) its work. but for column 'total_now' have null value. Its nessecary to add union??

Comment: that is because you are doing `left join` and maybe there isnt data to join. You was lucky I catch the alias error. Now to check the `NULL` I will need check some sample data.

Comment: [SOLVED] just change "ON la.member_api_domain = lb.member_api_domain AND la.member_api_campaign = lb.member_api_campaign"

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` must include all columns you select.
In `SQL Server 2005+`, you can use [OVER() clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), like this:

```
SELECT member_created, member_api_domain, member_api_campaign,
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(member_created)= MONTH(NOW()) THEN member_total_point) OVER(PARTITION BY member_api_campaign) AS 'total',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(member_created)= MONTH(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN member_total_point) OVER(PARTITION BY member_api_campaign) AS 'total now'
FROM lalights_member 
WHERE YEAR(member_created)=2014 
AND (MONTH(member_created)= MONTH(NOW()) OR MONTH(member_created)= MONTH(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
ORDER BY member_api_campaign DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) i'm used MySQL 5.1 sir, function OVER() can't be applied..